# starting with reactive DB access in a blocking monolith

Tags: wildfly, quarkus, vert.x

In a DB heavy monolith based on wildfly. does it make sense to transform the DB access to reactive one for starters? should I see performance benefits?

also, the DB is sybase and the only 'generic' jdbc driver I know is from vert.x but this implies that I will have to put vert.x inside my wildfly. I understand that they are sort of alternatives but I cant find any other options.

I would love to hear your thoughts about the 2 points I am raising. In general, I cant commit to a full transition from wildfly to quarkus/vert.x from the get go as it will take lots of resources so I thought I could start smaller...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vert.x is a *toolkit*, which means, for example, you do not need to use the web server it provides, nor any other module. It's also very lightweight, so you will only add a few more dependencies to your application. So, yes it can make sense to integrate Vert.x.

`vertx-jdbc-client` however, cannot magically transform blocking calls into non-blocking calls. Instead, it will off-load the blocking calls onto Vert.x' *worker thread pool*. That will lead to another effect: The DB call you *used to wait for*, will immediately return, leaving you with nothing but a `Future`. That Future will *eventually* have the expected result.

Going further *upstream* in your code (the direction where your user's request came from), this means that you will have to

1. *either* defer processing of the result via `Future.map()` or `Future.compose()`
2. block the thread to get the result immediately

You will win nothing by (2), so rule that out.

When you go for (1), you **must defer all further processing**, up to the point where the incoming request is originally handled. If that is, for example, a `Servlet`, you have to use [*Asynchronous Processing*](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets012.htm) to make sure that Wildfly does not commit the response after the `doGet`, `doPost` etc. method exits.

The result of all this will be that Wildfly now handles your request asynchronously, with Vert.x managing the DB interaction. *You can do that*. But it would be more idiomatic to your current setup to just use Asynchronous Processing (or Spring's `@Async` feature) and wrap all of your code in a `Runnable`. Both approaches will **not** speed up request processing itself, because the processing depends on the slower DB. However, Wildfly will be able to process more requests because the threads it assigns to requests will not be blocked anymore.

Having all that said, if you want to migrate to Quarkus in small steps, you should do that *service by service*. Identify the `Servlet`s (or `Controller`s) which do the work, and port them one by one to Quarkus. If sessions are your problem, then you could possibly share them between Wildfly and Quarkus, using Infinispan.